# Listen to stream event in template helper in Meteor

Tags: events, meteor, stream

I'm using rocketchat's meteor streamer package, and I've initiated the Streamer variable like so:

```
const Streamer = new Meteor.Streamer('chat', {retransmitToSelf: true});
export default Streamer;
```

So i have this code on the client:

```
import Streamer from '/imports/stream.js'
Template.chat.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var message = event.target.message.value;
        event.target.message.value = "";
        Streamer.emit('chat', message);

    }
})
//If I add this following code outside the Template.chat.events, it will listen wherever I am on the site, I only want it to actively listen when he is visiting the chat.
Streamer.on('chat', function(message) {
  console.log(message);
})
```

So how do I listen to the Streamer.on event inside the Template.chat.events?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Streamer but have you tried placing the `Streamer.on` call inside the `Template.chat.onCreated` lifecycle event?

Comment: @chazsolo yes thats exactly what I did, I just forgot to write it here, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting the block inside the template.chat.onCreated().
And then I put the Streamer.stop('chat') inside the template.chat.onDestroyed().